# openpyxl barchart LibreOffice compatibility issue

Tags: python, openpyxl, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, gnumeric

I want to create an Excel file using pythons `openpyxl` like in this video: https://youtu.be/fqvZZp2q2uE

Code is easy:

```
# See full Toturial at my Youtube Channel(YB TV): https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCvnhhDKv5takEN412dmVW8g/featured
# GitHab Page:https://github.com/yasser64b/
#Email: big3del@gmail.com

from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.chart import BarChart, Reference, Series, LineChart, ScatterChart
from openpyxl.styles import Font, Color, colors

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
for i in range(10):
    ws.append([i])

# drawing a graph
values = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=1, max_col=1, max_row=10)
# chart = LineChart()
chart = BarChart()
ws.add_chart(chart, "A15")
chart.title = "Chart"
chart.y_axis.title = 'Size'
chart.x_axis.title = 'Test Number'
chart.add_data(values)

s1 = chart.series[0]
s1.marker.symbol = "triangle"



wb.save("Chart-1.xlsx")
```

But I have problems opening it with LibreOffice Calc:

[image: LibreOffice Calc]

If opening with Gnumeric it looks better:

[image: Gnumeric]

What can I do to make the .xlsx file more compatible with LibreOffice Calc?

Comment: Looks like a bug in LibreOffice to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug in LibreOffice that will be fixed in version 7.1.0:

https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=137734

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specifically need to use LibreOffice, but simply a free equivalent of excel, you can use OpenOffice. From my experience it works better with openpyxl.

Comment: With Gnumeric I already have a better working Excel alternative. I would prefer to open it with LibreOffice.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not a very useful solution, as you need access to MS Excel, but for me it works to open the file in MS Excel first, save it from there, and then open it in LibreOffice (not sure whether this works with Gnumeric too; somehow my Gnumeric version refuses to open Openpyxl-generated charts).

This is a lot of hassle and, as said, useless if you don't have access to MS Excel, so if anyone is aware of a more direct solution, I'd love to hear it.